# Update OverlayEntry on scroll in SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am building the custom  dropdown using the OverlayEntry with Positioned inside

```
 OverlayEntry _createFloatingDropdown() {
    return OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      // yPosition = yPosition! + 56 - widget.scrollController.offset;
      return Positioned(
        left: xPosition,
        top: yPosition! + 56,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 200,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

This overlay dropdown is inserted onTap of my widget.

```
return InkWell(
      key: actionkey,
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (isDropdownOpen) {
            floatingDropdown.remove();
          } else {
            findDropDownData();
            floatingDropdown = _createFloatingDropdown();
            Overlay.of(context)?.insert(floatingDropdown);
          }

          isDropdownOpen = !isDropdownOpen;
        });
      },
```

The problem is that this InkWell widget is inside of SingleChildScrollView and after rendering the dropdown overlay its position is not updated on scroll, making my positioned widget fixed on the same position on the screen. How can I notify the overlay dropdown and make it update or rebuild on scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to add a scroll controller listener and remove and insert again overlay with the correct updated offset, but not sure if it is a good solution.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    actionkey = LabeledGlobalKey(widget.text);
    widget.scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _onScroll() {
    if (isDropdownOpen) {
      setState(() {
        floatingDropdown.remove();
        findDropDownData();
        floatingDropdown = _createFloatingDropdown();

        Overlay.of(context)?.insert(floatingDropdown);
      });
    }
  }
```